# Unable to use 3D X and 2D y for training

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, data-analysis

I am training a model to differentiate between real and fake data.
I have a real dataset and a fake dataset, and since I didn't know how to train a single model on both, I am now training a model for real and a model for fake.

The problem is that training any of the models seems impossible, as I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input X contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float16')
```

For this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

scaler = RobustScaler()
X = np.load("fake_x.npy")
x_data_flat = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1)
x_data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_data_flat)
y = np.load("fake_y.npy")
x_data_flat, y = shuffle(x_data_flat, y)
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x_data_scaled,y,test_size=0.1, train_size=0.1)

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)

print("Classification Report:")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))


conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print("Confusion Matrix:")
print(conf_matrix)
```

The data is certainly too large, x.shape = (750,1998,101) and y.shape = (750,496).
Data Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EYnOIOWP17ALs-903ESFM-02_6VszJEx
For the classification itself, I wouldl use a similarity score on the input and whoever gets a higher similarity score the input will belong to its class.

Using a 2D spectrogram that was originally real.npz but extracted to real_x.npy and real_y.npy to make it easier, the model should recognize whether the input belongs to real or to the fake.npz which I extracted to fake_x.npy and fake_y.npy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merged the fake and real data into a single matrix, and created a binary vector `y` where `1` means real and `0` means fake. The data had some invalid values (`np.inf`), which I replaced with the maximum allowable value for `float16`. I trained a classifier and got 87% classification accuracy on the validation set.

You'll probably also want to split a test set off. In the code I just worked with a training set and a validation set.

Output:

```py
Accuracy: 0.87
Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.84      0.89      0.87       141
         1.0       0.90      0.85      0.87       159

    accuracy                           0.87       300
   macro avg       0.87      0.87      0.87       300
weighted avg       0.87      0.87      0.87       300

Confusion Matrix:
[[126  15]
 [ 24 135]]
```

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

#
# Load the real and fake data, and stack into a single matrix
#
data_real = np.load('real.npz')['x']
data_fake = np.load('fake.npz')['x']
data = np.concatenate([data_real, data_fake], axis=0)

#Target vector: y=1 corresponds to real, and y=0 corresponds to fake
y = np.concatenate([np.ones(len(data_real)), np.zeros(len(data_fake))])

#Deal with inf by replacing with max value allowed
X = np.nan_to_num(data, posinf=np.finfo(data.dtype).max)
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1) #flatten

#Spline into train and validation sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, train_size=0.8, shuffle=True, random_state=0
)

#Optionally reduce the dimensionality
# This signficantly speeds up the clf.fit() step (from 40s down to 3s)
# It also reduces memory consumption
# But accuracy goes down from about 87% to 77%
# Could be useful for speeding up exploratory analyses
reduce_dimensionality = False
if reduce_dimensionality:
    from sklearn.random_projection import SparseRandomProjection
    projector = SparseRandomProjection(n_components='auto', random_state=0).fit(X_train)    
    X_train, X_test = [projector.transform(x) for x in [X_train, X_test]]

#Fit classifier
np.random.seed(0)
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=400)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)

print("Classification Report:")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print("Confusion Matrix:")
print(conf_matrix)
```